# Run Hadoop Mapper in Sequence

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have this task with multiple mappers, Map 1 and Map 2. I need it to be executed specifically in this way: Map1->Map2->Reducer. How do I do so? Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at the  ChainMapper

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html

> The ChainMapper class allows to use multiple Mapper classes within a
>   single Map task.

**UPDATE**  OP was concerned the maps are not sequential. That is not the case - as verified in the source code comments and in the code itself:

```
Mapper mapper = chain.getFirstMap();
if (mapper != null) {
  mapper.map(key, value, chain.getMapperCollector(0, output, reporter),
             reporter);
}
```

Comment: ChainMapper doesn't seem to allow sequential execution... it runs both maps together, it seems.

Comment: Not true: I have verified in the source code and updated the answer